# Getting erroneous "Maximum number of warnings has been exceeded"

Tags: vb.net, compiler-warnings

I inherited a VB.Net solution (VS2005) that I've just cleaned up.

I've gotten a clean build except for this warning:

Warning 1   Maximum number of warnings has been exceeded.

I could understand the first error if I actually had 100 warnings, but I don't. I'm a stickler for clean builds. Any ideas why I'd still be getting this message?

Comment: Does this happen for only this solution?  You sure that Visual Studio's settings are so that the Warnings are displayed?

Comment: Like I said, I just cleaned up the solution, fixing over 100 compiler warnings, so yes they are being displayed.

Comment: I just created a new VB.Net class library solution, with an empty class in it. No compiler warnings, no errors. I don't think it's a problem with VS2005.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You Have Unloaded file in your Project
if you work in team and use source control like TFS make sure other developer checking in all file like entity model and etc..

if your problem does not solve after this step remove all file in "Temporary ASP.NET files" and close your visual studio

last way for resolve this error is changing target framework in solution and then Return it to previous state

I hope your problem will be resolved after this steps :)